# How to format a Seagate HDD to OS X Extended (Journal) with Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-utility, partition, external-disk

I have just got a new external hard disk, the Seagate Expansion 2 TB, and I am trying to format it to work on my Mac. I was told that I had to erase the disk and format it to OS X Extended (Journal) with the Disk utility program.

However, *Disk Utility* won't allow me to erase it, and the partition button is greyed out. I will attach some screenshots of the problem:

[image: Partition button is greyed out] 
[image: This is the error message that pops up when i try to erase it]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You may try formatting from the console. Here's the help topic for you: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84098/how-do-i-force-a-partition-and-format-on-a-usb-key-in-os-x-mountain-lion-disk-ut

Comment: This looks to complicated for me to handle, hopefully i'll find another way. I don't wanna mess around with terminal unless there is no other option.

Comment: @MatsSchibbye Did you try to choose the **superior** Seagate item and erase that one? Use the GUID scheme!

Comment: @klanomath, is it the thing I outlined in the answer, right? to select the HDD, not the friendly name that appears under it?

Comment: @farside Yeah that's it . But I didn't read your answer completely because of the 1st sentence. You can always format and erase mounted drives except they contain a lot of important open files (e.g the boot volume).

Comment: thanks, @klanomath, for the input, I re-aranged the answer, so the most important thing comes first :)

Comment: @Farside I should have added: You can always format and erase mounted drives **because they are unmounted automatically before the disks are processed** except...

Comment: Thank you both! I had to choose the one above, can't believe i hadn't tried that before! Oh well, thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Disk Utility find the HDD you are trying to format in the left hand column. Select **the disk** and **not** the volume - that appears as child under it - to repartition it.

Just choosing the volume erases or replaces the file system but not the partition table type. This may apparently fail if the partition map is mal-formed.

[image]

If you feel confident with terminal, you may use instructions from other topics, [alike this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84098/how-do-i-force-a-partition-and-format-on-a-usb-key-in-os-x-mountain-lion-disk-ut).

Comment: I tried un-mounting the hard drive, it still won't let me press the partition button, or erase the disk. I don't know a thing about terminal, so hopefully i'll find another solution

Comment: which row do you try to select? please, find out my edited answer.

Comment: Looks like the one on top will let me erase, so do i choose GUID partition map, Apple partition map, or Master boot record? I will only use it on my mac and only need one partition

Comment: @MatsSchibbye, feel free to up-vote and accept the answer, as it appears to help you to solve the issue. Thank you, welcome!

Comment: @klanomath, I removed the redundant texts, which probably would not be helpful. thank you for the corrections! It seems this input helped the guy to solve his issue, and this is good